# The module does not know its known package in Python

Tags: python, module, package

I have some slight problems with importing my own module.
My project is structured into something like below.

```
src/  
|-- utils/  
|----- __init__.py  
|----- foo_a.py  
|----- foo_b.py  
|-- main.py
```

**main.py**

```py
from utils import foo_b
```

**foo_a.py**

```py
def func_a():
    print ("Hello World")
```

**foo_b.py**

```py
from foo_a import func_a
    func_a()
```

If I run `python foo_b.py` it works.
But when I run `python main.py`, it shows the error like this:
`"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo_a'"`

I can get around the problem by:
`export PYTHONPATH = path_of_utils_folder`

But this is just annoying. 
So I am wondering if the way I structure my project is not correct or is it because of the way I import the module?

Thank you.

Comment: Try `from .utils import foo_b` as a relative import

Comment: @coldspeed, That still produces error. But I tried this in `foo_b.py`. `from . import foo_a` and it works. So yeah, problem solved. Thank you

Comment: I thought the problem was with `main.py`, though?

Comment: @coldspeed Oh wait. False alarm. with the new changes, it works when I run `python main.py`, but not `python foo_b.py`.

Answer (score 0):

foo_a.py isn't instance so you can't use as module you can use from utils import ...

this is wrong usage >>> from foo_a import

if you want using from foo_a

you need something in foo_a such as:

in foo_a;

```
def plus(a,b):
    return(a+b)
```

now, you can use that from foo_a import plus 
but you can't use that from foo_a import plussss

because plusss isn't in foo_a

for usage plusss should in foo_a

Comment: thanks for the answer. But in my `foo_a.py` file, there is a function named `func_a()`